# Ember js app load from the beginning instead of using willtransition hook

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Hello everyone I'm using ember 3.1. The problem I get is when I move to view my profile page from the dashboard instead of just transitioning it loads the whole page which in result slows down my app. My router.js is like this:

```js
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('login', { path: 'login' });
  this.route('main', { path: '/' }, function () {
    this.route('dashboard', { path: '' }, function () {});
    this.route("review", { path: "/review/:docId" }, function() { 
      this.route("edit", { path: "/edit/:bitId" });
      this.route('window_edit');
    });
    this.route("view", { path: "/view/:docId" });
    this.route('pending_view',{ path: "/pending_view/:docId" });
    this.route('profile');
    this.route('loading');
  });
```

When I go to for example route `main.view` it goes directly without loading the whole page. It pass through `willTransition()` hook I added in my `app/route.js` file but the profile page goes through `model()` .
Will appreciate any help on this.

Linking is done as this:

```js
<button type="button" class="site-header__user " onClick={{action "toggleUserMenu" }}>

    <img src="/assets/images/icons/user.svg" alt="" id="userImage" class="userPicture" />

    <ul class="user-menu {{if (eq showMenu true) " open" "" }} {{if (eq showMenu false) "close" "" }}">
      <li class="user-menu__item">{{#link-to "main.profile"}}  profile {{/link-to}}</li>
      <li class="user-menu__item">{{#link-to "main.dashboard"}} dashboard {{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
</button>
```

Comment: Are you using `link-to` to generate the link?

Comment: @BuckDoyle Yes I am using link-to but in a button like this:
```<button onClick={{action "toggleUserMenu" }}>
 <img src="/assets/images/icons/user.svg"  />
<ul class="user-menu {{if (eq showMenu true) " open" "" }} {{if (eq showMenu false) "close" "" }}">
      <li class="user-menu__item">{{#link-to "main.profile"}} profile {{/link-to}}</li>
      <li class="user-menu__item">{{#link-to "main.dashboard"}} dashboard{{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
</button>```

Comment: hmm, links in buttons could cause problems, but that’s probably unrelated. When you say “it loads the whole page” are you meaning that it’s fetching a new HTML page etc vs the transition being handled within Ember?